# .NET SQL Server connection being prematurely closed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a .NET program using SQL Server 2008 SP3 Express. Both program and server are on the same machine. It was written with a connection that's opened initially and kept open thereafter. Usually this works OK. But sometimes the program is left idle for hours, during which time the connection is closed and the program bombs on the next SQL access.

The database Auto Close parameter is off. The parameter Pooling=False is in the program connection string. In IIS, for each application pool, recycling has been disabled and idle timeout has been set to 9000 minutes.

In testing so far, this works more often than not, but sometimes does not.

Comment: What connection type are you using ? My suggestion is that you can set  ConnectionTimeout property to 0. Which establish a connection for unlimited duration.

Comment: It's almost always better to create and open a new connection object inside the method that needs to use it, use it and then close it. Why are you disabling Pooling?

Comment: Trying to resolve this for an older version in the field; latest version does it right. Pooling disabled since IIS pool manager seemed to be closing it. Will try ConnectionTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to check the connection state and open it if necessary:

```
if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)//Can't quite remember the exact syntax
{
    conn.Open();
}
//do DB stuff here.
```

Comment: It should be `conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed`